# Product of currents

Tags: differential-geometry, distribution-theory

De Rham currents are for differential forms as distributions are to (smooth) functions. There is a notion of exterior product for differential forms: I wonder whether there is an algebra structure on currents (for example: there is an algebra structure on $C^{\infty}(M)$ however there is no good notion of product of two *general* distribution).

Comment: Certainly not without somehow enlarging the space of currents. As you note, there is no notion of a product on the space of distributions, but an algebra of currents restricted to degree 0 would be an algebra of distributions.